# In Android how can I show a very long text (190 words), is there any idea better then textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, longtext

I have a long text, about almost 1000 character including spaces (190 words). I tried to show that on a large textview, but it wasn't that great, didn't look pro, so is there any other idea?

Thanks for helping, and for trying to help.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't look pro, also the whole text looked really bad with the indentation I wanted on my text

Comment: "Not looking pro" isn't specific, and we don't know what indentation you wanted.

Comment: Er... In any case, add specifics to the question itself.

Comment: I just did, I was trying to give example on my question but all my indented text were canceled when I post, so I took them off, but now after I read stackoverflow instrucitons I was able to put an example.

Comment: Use a WebView if you want rich text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a WebView and pull the data from your resources? The data you load into a webview can come from anywhere, including a local file.

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Interesting way, I read the link, and the example, a bit lengthy process though.

Comment: You can also style a string using the static Html class. eg `Html.fromHtml('my <b>long</b> text');` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

wrap the text view in a ScrollView, then it doesn't matter how long your text is.

Comment: I tried that one already, but didn't link when I wanted to make a sub-point like this:

Comment: I can't seem to be able to show this in here, but text example is a main text, then the sub text example are suppose to be under text example with some space on the left kind of the same idea as (<ul><li>) in html
-  Text example
    - sub text example </br >
    - sub text example </br >